# Suitable http status code for extra authentication step when it's not provided or didn't match

Tags: rest, api, http, http-status

#### Problem

The application expects the client to send the header `Authorization` with the access token on most of the routes. Now there is a new feature and some new few routes expect not only the `Authorization` header but also a `pin` attribute with a 6-length string inside the body of the request. If the `pin` value does not match the user's `pin` stored in the database, the request should be refused.

Which status code should be used to refuse the request since the **user is authenticated** (it sent a valid access token in the `Authorization` header) but sent a wrong `pin` value?

#### Context

This application will now support payments and the routes that need the `pin` attribute inside the body of the request are routes that make the payments, so they spend the user's credits inside the application. That's why it needs to send the `pin` only on a few routes.

#### Solutions I thought

1. Use `422 Unprocessable Entity` since the request can not be processed because of the wrong `pin` value inside the body.

   - **Problem:** the status code `422` is also sent when some other validation fails, so it doesn't seem right since the `pin` is more related to authorization.
2. Use `401 Not Authorized` since a wrong `pin` value means the user failed to give all the proper credentials.

   - **Problem:** the user actually gave proper credentials for what the application expected on every route til now. The *needed credentials to be considered authenticated in the application* won't match after the new feature. The `401` will now mean two kinds of errors instead of *user is not authenticated* only.
3. Use `403 Forbidden`.

   - **Problem:** although the user is *not allowed*, this is not a matter of role permissions.

*Extra question: is it better for the `pin` to be sent in the headers instead of the body?*

Answer (score 0):

I think 422, 403 and 400 are all 'ok enough'. I would probably go for 400 because it is a bit more of a unique situation, and none of the status codes IMHO fit perfectly.